# Unable to run capedwarf.sh <path>

Tags: java, google-app-engine, capedwarf

Running `capedwarf.sh <path>` throws this error:

```
03:08:16,369 INFO  [org.restlet] (Thread-0 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-266112928)) Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
03:08:16,440 WARNING [org.restlet.Component.Server] (Thread-0 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-266112928)) Error while handling an HTTP server call: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal.ServletCall.getVersion(ServletCall.java:370) [org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.3.5.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.toRequest(ServerAdapter.java:226) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.internal.ServletServerAdapter.toRequest(ServletServerAdapter.java:62) [org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.3.5.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:141) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117) [org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.3.5.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.appidentity.GAEFilter.doFilter(GAEFilter.java:62) [capedwarf-appidentity-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchMockRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:235) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.mock(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:425) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.capedwarf.services.Hack.invoke(Hack.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.capedwarf.services.ServletExecutor.dispatch(ServletExecutor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.capedwarf.services.ServletExecutorConsumer.onMessage(ServletExecutorConsumer.java:126)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:103)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1116)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1251)
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
```

The app is a Restlet Framework (version 2.3.5) based backend.

Comment: It's a warning. But NPE is always a bug. See why this NPE is thrown, and perhaps workaround it in some custom web filter? Or if you can narrow down the problem in CapeDwarf + provide a test,
I can try and fix this. Since tasks' requests are not real requests, we could be easily missing some header, attribute, etc

Comment: @alesj the issue is causing TaskQueue tasks from running from what I see

Comment: This looks like an issue in restlet to me.

Comment: I am not sure since this same war file is the one deployed to GAE (appspot) and works fine also works on Appscale.

Comment: This gives more context to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621519/taskqueue-failing-to-do-http-call-missing-mandatory-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Capedwarf, and it seems it requires the host header where App Engine doesn't. You may solve this issue by adding the host header manually to your task, like this:

```
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(taskUrl)
    .header("Host","your_host_name")
    .param("param1", param1));
```