# Cannot access './../modules/com/google/appengine/main/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-*-capedwarf*': No such file or directory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, capedwarf

Running Capedwarf shows this error:

```
xybrek@ubuntu:~/CapeDwarf_WildFly_2.0.0.Final/bin$ ./capedwarf.sh /path/to/war
ls: cannot access './../modules/com/google/appengine/main/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-*-capedwarf*': No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /home/xybrek/CapeDwarf_WildFly_2.0.0.Final/modules/com/google/appengine/main/module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:155)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:132)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:154)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:148)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:305)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1036)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1406)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1434)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:385)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24-capedwarf.jar' at path 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24-capedwarf.jar' (position: END_TAG seen ...</filter>\n        </resource-root>... @33:25) caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/xybrek/CapeDwarf_WildFly_2.0.0.Final/modules/com/google/appengine/main/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24-capedwarf.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseResourceRoot(ModuleXmlParser.java:723)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:572)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:394)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:219)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:153)
    ... 13 more
=========================================================================
```

What could be the fix for this? There's no such jar anywhere.

Comment: The only file in the path is `appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bytecode modification didn't yet kick in.
(we modify GAE API jar on the fly the first time, as we need some bytecode hacks)

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621519/taskqueue-failing-to-do-http-call-missing-mandatory-headers